# Rendering Vue Components in HTML from a Database

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

I am using Spring in my backend and scraping news articles from websites for a personal project. I am getting everything I need via Jsoup, but I am at the point where I need to start retrieving all the tweets from every article.

Strategy (that isnt working):
I scrape every article using jsoup and save the html I get into my database, retrieve each article via their id, and using the format provided in the vue-tweet-embed (https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-tweet-embed) package - I render the tweet using the link I scrape from the articles. Its so far working the way I expect it, but here's the problem:

I believe once I retrieve all of the html from my database IT IS rendering correctly, BUT it isnt recognizing the vue component using v-html, but without v-html I think it just recognizes it as markup, here is the java/vue and the html its iterating over, I've shortened it from my original:

### JAVA:

```
`Elements aTags = paragraph.select("a[href*=twitter.com]");
                     for (Element aTag : aTags) {
                        String tweetUrl = aTag.attr("href").split("\\?")[0];
                                content.append("<Tweet tweet-url=" + "'" + tweetUrl + "'>" + "</Tweet>" + System.lineSeparator() + System.lineSeparator());                           }`
```

### VUE:

```
`<template>
    <div class="container">
                <div v-for="content in article" v-bind:key="content.id" >
                    <h1 style="font-size: 50px; text-align: left; font-weight: bolder;">{{ content.title }}</h1>
                    <img class="article-image" :src=content.urlToImage>
                    <h4>read from the original source here:</h4> <a class="a-article" v-bind:href="content.url" target="__blank"> {{ content.url }}</a>
                    <Tweet></Tweet>
                    <div class="content" v-html="content.text"></div>
                    <CommentSection :articleId="content.article_id"></CommentSection>
                </div>
              </div>
    </div>  
    
    </template>

 data() {
        return {
//article content
          article: [],
    }

created() {
//gets article Content
      ArticleService.getArticleContent(this.$route.params.id).then(response => {
        this.article = response.data
        // console.log(this.article)
      }),
    }`
```

#### HTML to Be Rendered from the article object Snippet

```
`<p>The Celtics thought it was funny — Jaylen Brown jokingly offered Blake Griffin his mask after the Bucks’ Thanasis Antetokounmpo headbutted the Celtic forward.</p>

<p>The NBA didn’t find it as amusing and suspended Antetokounmpo for one game for the incident.</p>

<p>Thanasis ejected after head-butting Blake Griffin  pic.twitter.com/gaQSIiFX59</p>

<p>— Bleacher Report (@BleacherReport) March 31, 2023</p>

<tweet tweet-url="https://twitter.com/BleacherReport/status/1641617577003880448"></tweet>

<p></p>

<p>Griffin was given a Flagrant 1 foul at the time, but mostly the Celtics had a good laugh.</p>

<p>Jaylen really gave Blake his mask @FCHWPO @blakegriffin23 pic.twitter.com/Gwn9AckWP3</p>

<tweet tweet-url="https://twitter.com/FCHWPO"></tweet>

<tweet tweet-url="https://twitter.com/blakegriffin23"></tweet>

<p>— Celtics on NBC Sports Boston (@NBCSCeltics) March 31, 2023</p>

<tweet tweet-url="https://twitter.com/NBCSCeltics/status/1641617185511464961"></tweet>`
```

#### Last thought

When I copy and paste the tweets from the html directly into my code file in VSCode it renders just fine so Im assuming the v-html directive isn't recognizing the tweet tags as a component and just as plain html divs.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to correctly render the tweet components like I am trying to do, or maybe a better way to scrape the tweets?

Comment: This looks like XY problem. This is atypical use of Vue. It's possible to achieve this but not advisable. Instead api can respond with enough data to add <Tweet> inside Vue app template, i.e. a list of urls

Comment: You can create and register a WebComponent for the `<tweet>` tags - then the browser will render them even inside `v-html`